# Custom browse button jQuery code not working in Safari browser

Tags: jquery, html, safari

Below is the jQuery code for custom browse button which works perfectly in `Google Chrome` and `Mozilla Firefox`.
But it is not working in `Safari`.

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('change', ':file', function() {
    var input = $(this),
    numFiles = input.get(0).files ? input.get(0).files.length : 1,
    label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
    input.trigger('fileselect', [numFiles, label]);
  });

  $(document).ready( function() {
    $(':file').on('fileselect', function(event, numFiles, label) {
      var input = $(this).parents('.input-group').find(':text'),
      log = numFiles > 1 ? numFiles + ' files selected' : label;
      if( input.length ) {
        input.val(log);
      } else {
        if( log ) alert(log);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/te1c7h3L/1/)

Comment: please share your full code with html and css

Comment: @ Shital ,it is given in demo link, whole code